# Using for each to compare multiple columns in each workbooks and copy a third colum over to one of the workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I am matching two columns in a new workbook with two columns in Workbook 2, and then retrieving column B from Workbook2 and copying it to column B in the new workbook.  Some cells will be empty.  Running the following code results in nothing being copied over. I'm not sure if I am using the right approach to retrieve the information.

```
    Sub InsertDeviceName_NewBook()

      Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet, wsnew As Worksheet
      Dim wbnew As Workbook
      Dim c As Range, FR As Variant
      Dim d As Range
      Dim e As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
      Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long


      Application.ScreenUpdating = False


      Set w2 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").ActiveSheet
      Set w1 = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").ActiveSheet



     w1.Range("B:D").Copy
     Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add 'creates new workbook
     Columns("A:A").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     ActiveSheet.Name = w1.Name
     Set wsnew = wbnew.ActiveSheet 'sets the active sheet in the new workbook
     lr1 = wsnew.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     lr2 = w2.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


     wsnew.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With wsnew.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C" & lr1)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
   End With

Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

      Range("B1").Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Device Name"

      Dim lr3 As Long

      lr3 = wsnew.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

      Set rng1 = wsnew.Range("C2:D" & lr3)
      Set rng2 = w2.Range("C2:D" & lr2)

'create a loop to find matches between columns C and D in the new workbook
'and match with columns C and D in workbook 2, upon a match retrieve the information
'in column B in workbook2 and add it to Columns B in the new workbook

For Each d In rng1
    FR = Application.Match(d, rng2)
    If IsNumeric(FR) Then
    d.Offset(, -1).Value = w2.Range("B" & FR).Value
    End If

Next d

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't an Index Match formula work here? This would capture the values which match each other, then you could basically copy the results and paste as value.

This example uses a single cell as the return, but you could change it to be a row formula and return the proper results for each row.

[Index Match With Multiple Criteria Example](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria)

Comment: I'll see if Index Match will work, thanks.  Unfortunately copying the entire row will over write the information for the row that I am copying to.  I only need the value from the one column to be added to the worksheet.

Comment: I am not understanding why you would need to "copy the entire row". If there is no need to truly copy the information, then I would only implement the index-match formula. This would give you the result of having any matching information from the workbook2 indexed column into the cell where the formula is written.

Comment: I think Index-Match is THE solution that you want unless I am totally missing something. I would suggest that you learn how to implement that. Try using the formula with single matching criteria instead of multiple first. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-H3UmBUIDYI